# Which simulator I can use to do function testing for BB mobile application?

Tags: mobile

I work in QA and I am looking for a simulator to test on a Mobile application for the Black Berry Bold and Curve.

Comment: Welcome to SQA&T... your question is quite broad - can you narrow down your requirements a bit. As this stands, it is likely to be closed as "Not Constructive"

Comment: @Andrew, I'm not an expert in this domain. Are they really so many Black Berry phone emulators that the author must be more specific?

Comment: One of the hallmarks of a solid StackExchange question is prior effort. Marya, perhaps you could provide some detail as to what your current process is, and what you've found so far?

Comment: There is no evidence of even a basic google search being done.  RIM provides blackberry simulators (with different skins) in their free development kit.

Answer (score 2):

RIM's [website](http://us.blackberry.com/sites/developers/resources/simulators.html) appears to have the simulator's that you would probably be looking for.

For thorough testing however, if it's just these two particular devices, you will probably want to get the physical devices to test on as behavior can vary between simulators and the actual devices.